# How can I delet an axvspan line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with a time series and one or several axvspan lines to highlight some areas and to extract the time series value and instant but I would like to have the possibility to delete one or all those axvspan lines with a button. I have looked some examples on how to delete lines ([How can I delete plot lines that are created with Mouse Over Event in Matplolib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819260/how-can-i-delete-plot-lines-that-are-created-with-mouse-over-event-in-matplolib/17820452#comment26010581_17820452)) but I can´t find nothing related with axvspan lines.
This is the code that I'm using to create the axvspan line(s)

```
    def on_click(event):
        global x0
        x0 = event.xdata

    def on_release(event):
        global force_values
        if force_value == "Min":
            self.axes.axvspan(x0,event.xdata, facecolor='y', alpha=0.5)
            get_data(frames,force_values,x0,event.xdata)
        else:
            self.axes.axvspan(x0,event.xdata, facecolor='r', alpha=0.5)
            get_data(frames,force_values,x0,event.xdata)
```

Thanks in advance for your help. 
Kind Regards 
Ivo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost all `artist` objects have a `remove` member function which will remove them from axes:

```
aspan = self.axes.axvspan(x0,event.xdata, facecolor='y', alpha=0.5)
# do stuff
aspan.remove()
plt.draw()
```

If you need to do a bunch of them, then you just need to keep track of a bunch of them

```
self.aspan_list = []
self.aspan_list.append(self.axes.axvspan(x0,event.xdata, facecolor='y', alpha=0.5))
#...
for aspan in self.aspan_list:
    aspan.remove()
```

Comment: I wasn't assigning the axvspan to a variable so I was getting an error saying that axvspan doesn´t has that method (remove). Now I can finally delete the last axvspan that I create in my plot. Since I need to draw several axvspan in the same plot, and I would like to know if there is a way to delete all at once? I used the same code but when I press the delete axvspan button several times it will delete just the last axvspan and leave the others. Thank you for your help. Kind Regards. Ivo